# Designing MERGE-SORT Algorithm - VERY WEIRD ISSUE ! "std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00486F78."

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, visual-studio-2012

This is for an assignment in an algorithm class. I understand and agree that using a vector would simplify things, but that isn't an option.
The code for the Mergesort / merge algorithm can't be modified either.

I need to run the merge sort as follows:
starting from 100 all the way to 1000, increments of 100. For each increment I run it 5 times, for each of these times I run it 1000 times.

That being said - everything works fine until my loop reaches 700 and crashes with the error:  "Unhandled exception at 0x75612F71 in msdebug.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x010672F4."

Here is my code:

```
int const size = 6;
int const size2 = 1001;
int const times = 6;
int const interval = 11;  

void merge(int arr[], int p, int q, int r)
    {
        int n1 = q - p + 1;
        int n2 = r - q;
        int * L = new int[n1 + 1];
        int * R = new int[n2 + 1];    // line giving the error after 700
        for (int i = 1; i <= n1; i++)
        {
            L[i] = arr[p + i - 1];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= n2; j++)
        {
            R[j] = arr[q + j];
        }
        L[n1 + 1] = 32768;
        R[n2 + 1] = 32768;
        int i, j;
        i = j = 1;
        for (int k = p; k <= r; k++)
        {
            if (L[i] <= R[j])
            {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
        }


    }

    void mergeSort(int arr[], int p, int r)
    {
        int q;
        if (p < r)
        {
            q = ((p + r) / 2);
            mergeSort(arr, p, q);
            mergeSort(arr, (q + 1), r);
            merge(arr, p, q, r);


        }
    }

    void copyArray(int original[][size2], int copy[], int row, int finish)
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= finish)
        {
            copy[i] = original[row][i];
            i++;
        }

    }
    void copyOneD(int orig[], int cop[])
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < size2; i++)
        {
            cop[i] = orig[i];
        }
    }



    int main()
    {
        struct timeval;

        clock_t start, end;
        srand(time(NULL));

        int arr[size][size2];
        int arr2[size2];
        int arrCopy[size2];
        double tMergeSort[times][interval];
        double avgTmergeSort[11];


        /*for (int i = 1; i < (size2); i++)
        {
             arr2[i] = rand();
        }*/

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < size2; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = rand();
            }
        }


    for (int x = 100; x <= 1000; x = x + 100)   //This loop crashes >=700
        {
            for (int r = 1; r <= 5; r++)
            {
                copyArray(arr, arr2, r, 1001);

                for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
                {
                    copyOneD(arr2, arrCopy);
                    mergeSort(arrCopy, 1, x);
                }
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

You can ignore the code and the arrays. Those functions work fine. 
Everything works fine until I set 'x <= 700' or higher and then it crashes.

I had a theory that maybe the computer runs out of memory for the pointers in the merge algorithm but when I tried to use delete it also crashed.

Any help is appreciated and suggestions as well.

Thanks

Comment: Figuring out why it didn't work with `delete`s in there should be your focus. You can't just allocate more and more memory without deallocating it.

Comment: Also carefully check for off by one array errors. For example in your copyArray function the parameter 'finish' is given the value 1001 but the elements are stored only upto index 1000.

Comment: Not gonna sugar coat it. If your mergesort/merge implementation in C/C++ is sprinkled with `<=` , or `>=`, its likelihood of being wrong grows by leaps and bounds. Regardless, fix your memory leaks *first*.

Comment: How do I fix the memory leaks if delete isn't working for me ? The <= is because its a 1 based array so it goes from 1 to 1000 including.  The error I get with delete is "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#141) at 0x00743BBO. Application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer"

Comment: That is the runtime telling you you hosed the heap by writing beyond a dynamic allocation and invoking undefined behavior; not uncommon when implementing mergesort with equality-comparisons. That isn't something you ignore. It is something you **fix**. Your merge algorithm is highly likely broken, and frankly about 4x the amount of code it needs to be. I'd start there.

Comment: That is based off the psuedocode given by the professor; if anyone can help with a solution or point out where the problem lies specifically I would really appreciate it. I've been working on this for over 3 days now and all the other algs I've done have worked, this is the only one giving me so much trouble. I wouldn't post here unless I was out of options. I really need to know how to fix this. Also, this code works flawlessly until the outermost loop hits 700 or higher, this is whats really troubling me

Comment: Flawlessly? Even when you `delete[]` your dynamic allocations when finished with them?

Comment: So.. I'll ask you this. You should already know that arrays in C/C++ are indexible from 0...N-1, where N is the declared/allocated size, right? Sooooo. consider this: `int * L = new int[n1 + 1];`, the a few lines later, `L[n1 + 1] = 32768;`. Do you see a problem with that? `L` is indexible from `0...n1`. You're writing out of range. (Same issue with R, btw, and I see no sense in *either* of those lines assigning 32768; take them *both* out and put your `delete[]` s back).

Comment: I removed them and now it no longer crashes and the deletes work. However, now my merge sort doesn't. The array is no longer sorted when it comes out...  Those lines were there for comparison purposes as sentinal nodes, since rand() generates up until 32767, this will always be bigger

Comment: I re-added the lines, and I initialized L and R to [n1+2] and [n2+2] respectively. This solved everything and now it all works. I still don't know how and why and would love it if someone could help me understand why it even worked previously up to 700... either way thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: Good that it doesn't fault. You may consider alternative algorithms, in particular for your merge, but also for setting up temp-storage, which ideally should be done at-most-once. [See example here](http://ideone.com/sWgHy8). No sentinel values should be required or a mergesort algorithm. Done correctly, comparison operator outside `operator <` should be needed either. Just something to think about. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried playing around with my code since yesterday and although it runs and sorts correctly, its slow. It's running much slower then my quicksort and intertion sort algorithms and that doesn't make sense. Can you help me clean it up while still maintaining the same structure? or would you tell me where my main timing issue(s) is ? Also, I tried removing the sentinal values as you suggested but then it no longer sorted the numbers...

Comment: The sheer amount of `+1` and `<=` vs `<` in this code makes it much harder to maintain. This is C++. You need to learn to index starting at 0 through N-1 for a sequence of N length (or better still, use iterators and the standard library). The example I linked would be hard pressed to be any simpler than that, and should perform predictably with O(NlogN) complexity. With a single allocation up-front and no sub-allocations throughout the sort, it is pure algorithm at that point with minimal overhead from things like memory management. I don't know what else to tell you on that regard.